# Greet User by name using Javascript and query string

Tags: javascript, onload

I am trying to get the user's name from a form input and display it on the page in the form of a greeting "Hello (user)".
I have already got the solution to do it in 2 separate HTML files but I need to do it all in one file using query string and onload options.

Thanks for your help!

**firstpage.html**

```
<input type="text" id="titletxt">  
  <button onclick="Submit()">Submit</button>
  
  <script>
    function Submit() {
      let name = document.getElementById("txtname").value;
      window.location.href = "secondpage.html?" + name;
    }
  </script>
```

**secondpage.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
<script>
  function loadTitle() {

    let queryString = window.location.search.split('?')[1];
    
    document.write("<h2>Hello "+queryString+"</h2>")
    document.title = "hello "+queryString;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadTitle()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So are you asking for a solution where all of that code is in the same file?

Comment: Yes Please......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your secondpage.html body to:

```
<body onload="loadTitle()">
    <script>
      function loadTitle() {
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const name = new URLSearchParams(queryString).get("name");
        document.body.innerHTML = "<h2>Hello " + name + "</h2>";
        document.title = "hello " + name;
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: do you want to display the `hello user` message on the same page that sends the user name?

Comment: Yes please.....

Comment: hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer but  I need to use Query String to achieve the outcome and use  “onload” event in a function

Comment: can you provide the full code

Comment: That is the full code I came up with.

Comment: I need to read the user's name from the query string. plus I need to read the query string when the page is loaded, not when the button is pressed.

Comment: use the code inside `window.onload` function

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in believing that you wanted all of the code to be in one file, I have a solution for you.

**Solution with search params:**

It simply checks if there is a search parameter called 'name' and if there is is replaces everything with Hello [name].

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="titletxt">
    <button onclick="Submit()">Submit</button>
    <script>
        function loadTitle() {
            const queryString = window.location.search;
            const name = new URLSearchParams(queryString).get("name");
            if (name) {
                document.body.innerHTML = "<h2>Hello " + name + "</h2>";
                document.title = "Hello " + name;
            }
        }
        document.body.onload = loadTitle;

        function Submit() {
            let name = document.getElementById("titletxt").value;
            window.location.search = "?name=" + name;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```